# Get column values from a CSV file w/o for loops

Tags: php, excel, csv, scripting

I have a large CSV file in front of me.  10 Columns, 3000 rows.  I am looking for a PHP library that would let me simply get all the values in a given column.  Something like this:

`$columnValues = $file->getColumnValues('F');`

I have looked at:
http://pear.php.net/package/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer/

but this doesn't appear to have what I need....I could be wrong.  What I am NOT looking for is a foreach solution.

Comment: No such creature exists (and if it did, it would still need to loop); you will need to loop unless you sell to the command line and use awk .... but if the file is a CSV file than you loop with fgetcsv()

Comment: A database works great for this sort of thing :)

Comment: What's the difference if you loop or the utility functions loops through the rows? Or why don't you restructure the CSV array yourself if that's its main use?

Comment: unix cut command works good

Comment: @immulatin ... originally I didn't want to throw this data in a DB, for several reasons.  But after doing some more thinking, that is the way I am gonna go on this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Parse CSV is my favorite...although PHP's built in functions aren't that bad either...

[ParseCSV](https://code.google.com/p/parsecsv-for-php/wiki/Examples)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (PHP >= 5.1.0):

```
echo getRowColumnValue(__DIR__.'/csvtest.csv', 2, 1); // third row, second column

function getRowColumnValue($path, $row, $column, $delimiter = ';')
{
    $file = new SplFileObject($path);        
    $file->seek($row);
    //$cols = $file->fgetcsv($delimiter); // bug? gets next row
    $cols = str_getcsv($file->current(), $delimiter);
    return (isset($cols[$column])) ? $cols[$column] : null;
}
```

Or a little class with excel like alpha support:

```
// Example 1:
$file = new CsvFile(__DIR__.'/csvtest.csv');
$file->seekToRow(2);
echo $file->getColumnValue('B'); 
// also supports integers -> echo $file->getColumnValue(1);

// Example 2:
$file = new CsvFile(__DIR__.'/csvtest.csv');
print_r($file->getColumnValues('B')); // get column values as array -> row 2

class CsvFile extends SplFileObject
{
    public function __construct($filename, $delimiter = ';', $enclosure = "\"", $escape = "\\")
    {
        parent::__construct($filename);
        $this->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);
        $this->setCsvControl($delimiter, $enclosure, $escape);
    }

    protected function _getNumber($alpha)
    {
        $alpha = preg_replace("/[^A-Z]+/", "", strtoupper($alpha));
        $i = 0;
        $len = strlen($alpha);
        for ($j=0;$j<$len;$j++) {
            $i += (ord($alpha[$j]) - 65) + ($j * 26);
        }
        return $i;
    }

    public function seekToRow($row)
    {
        $row = (is_string($row)) ? $this->_getNumber($row) : $row;
        $this->seek($row);
    }

    public function getColumnValue($column)
    {
        $column = (is_string($column)) ? $this->_getNumber($column) : $column;
        $cols = $this->current();
        return (isset($cols[$column])) ? $cols[$column] : null;
    }

    public function getColumnValues($row)
    {
        $this->seekToRow($row);
        return $this->current();
    }
}
```